# R: plotmath expression symbols not showing up in interaction plot

Tags: r, plot, plotmath

For some reason, my interaction plots don't seem to show the greek symbols (latex) in R markdown (using R studio). The code I am using is reproduced below. Why are the expression() functions not working? Any suggestions?

```
with(ba_results, interaction.plot(as.factor(f1), as.factor(f2), 
                                  y,
                                  type = "b",
                                  pch = c(18, 19, 24),
                                  fixed = TRUE,
                                  xlab = "Scale factor",
                                  ylab = "Mean Response",
                                  trace.label = expression(mu_e),
                                  main = paste("Interaction plot of", 
                                               expression(mu[e]), 
                                               "f1")))
```

Comment: Can't run this. Can you add some simulated data as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the title, wrap the whole thing in `expression`. For example, `main = expression(paste("Interaction plot of ", mu[e], " f1"))` or `main = expression(Interaction~plot~of~mu[e]~f1)`.

For the `trace.label`, the `expression` is not being parsed properly. It looks like the problem is this line in the code for `interaction.plot`:

```
text(xleg, ylim[2L] - 0.05 * yrng, paste("  ", trace.label), adj = 0)
```

So `trace.label` is wrapped in `paste` which turns the expression back into a text string. For example:

```
expression(mu[e])
# expression(mu[e])

paste("  ", expression(mu[e]))
# "   mu[e]"
```

As a workaround, you can modify the function to use `trace.label` as is. To do that, get the code for `interaction.plot` by typing `interaction.plot` in the console. Copy the code into a new R script file and assign the function a new name like `my_interaction_plot`. Then change the line above to this:

```
text(xleg, ylim[2L] - 0.05 * yrng, trace.label, adj = 0)
```

This change will result in `expression(mu[e])` being parsed properly.

Now just use `my_interaction_plot` instead of `interaction.plot` like this:

```
with(ba_results, 
     my_interaction_plot(as.factor(f1), as.factor(f2), y, type = "b",
                         pch = c(18, 19, 24), fixed = TRUE,
                         xlab = "Scale factor", ylab = "Mean Response",
                         trace.label = expression(mu_e),
                         main = expression(paste("Interaction plot of ", mu[e], " f1"))))
```